# Windows 7 Recovery partition present but no option when booting

Tags: recovery-console, windows-7-restore

On my Dell Studio XPS1645 I have a 14,65GB Recovery partition with WindowsRE on it. The problem is that I have no "Boot in recovery" when I press F8 on the boot loader (it's the standard Windows boot loader, edited with EasyBCD to add a Linux partition). I can swear that the option was present time ago, and haven't changed nothing. What can I do?

Comment: Did you system prompt you to make recovery CDs/DVDs when you first got it (I'm sure you've thought of this, just wanted to cover all the bases)

Answer (score 1):

In your BIOS there should be an option to present boot options (usually with the F12 key, which is normally displayed along with the vendor's logo during POST) before the OS boots.  By pressing "F12" (during POST which occurs between powering up and before the boot process begins) you should be presented with a few options for where to boot from, and since the vendor placed that partition there it should be selectable.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  Backup your data before doing this because the factory reset tools that are normally placed on these partitions usually format the hard drive as part of the process and all pre-existing data gets erased.